# How can I position right my List Items?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 list items, and I don't know how can I position it to the right-top of the screen.

My sources:

```css
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 85em;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: .5em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="" src="" alt="">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">About Us</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I tried to position so many ways, but I can't did..

Comment: remove the huge padding and replace center of text-align by right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to place `<ul>` on `top-right` of a screen then add to your code

```
nav ul {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              right: 0;
}
```

**Or**

If you want to place **logo** on the left side of the screen and **nav** on the right of the screen then see this example: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thezeeshantariq/wu7L1865/5/)

Html will remain the same

**CSS**

```
img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

**OR**

You can use **flexbox**, the example is here: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thezeeshantariq/wu7L1865/7/)

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar">
        <img class="" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" alt="">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">About Us</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
 }

img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

nav {
  margin-left: auto;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: .5em;
  color: black;
  }
```